# How to use memoir change markers without the draft option

Tags: memoir, changes

After considerable thought and experimentation, I came to the conclusion that I wanted to use *memoir*'s `\changemarks` facility to indicate, as a courtesy to a client, where my proposal had changed as a result of our discussions.

However, `\changemarks` and friends are suppressed unless the `draft` class option is used. But using `draft` gives me some horrible side-effects, like missing graphics and blobs at the edge of my occasional(!) overfull box, as well as being semantically untrue.

I thought, initially, about latexdiff (barfs on my files), changebars (appears not to support xelatex), and changes (conflicts with memoir), and discarded them for the reasons mentioned. Now I'm heavily invested in the native memoir solution, I'm not sure which way to jump.

Can anyone suggest a reasonable quick fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick fix is redefining the internal macro `\v@rid`:

```
\documentclass[changemarks]{memoir}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\v@rid}[2]{%
  \@bsphack
  \ifchangemarks
     \marginpar[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
  \@esphack}
\makeatother
\changemarks
\begin{document}
\added{text}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
\end{document}​
```

Here, the change marks are shown without `draft`. Also, the black overfull hbox marker is not, shown, it would be if you activate the draft option.

Originally, that macro contained

```
\ifchangemarks
   \ifdraftdoc
     \marginpar[#1]{#2}%
\fi\fi
```

and I removed the `\ifdraftdoc` check by the redefinition above. This macro is used by `\added`, `\deleted` and `\changed`.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan, that's done the trick. I might try to put together a patch for @daleif to allow an optional parm to `changemarks` to override the draft/final document option.